# Force datagram reassembly

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing

Long story short: It is possible reassemble fragmented IP datagrams on Linux station which isn't datagrams destination?

What I want exactly. I have two vmware servers which communicates between each other. On one of them is set vmware port mirroring to third server where is some packet analyzer (actually it is a voice recording system). Problem is that mirrored datagrams are fragmented and "third" server is not able to reassemble them because it isn't packet destination. Packet analyzer then has a problem with reading those fragmented packets because does not contain any "packet reassembly operation". So, I want reassemble packet on Linux interface. It is possible?

Comment: Open a ticket with the  vendor of the voice snooping software/firmware.

Comment: Let's leave aside that is a recording server. So, It is possible? Just curiosity.

Comment: If it were the destination, I think it would be possible; as it is a passive device, that would be mostly corrected addressed by the vendor of the device.